# PHP MongoDB PDF Upload blob Issue

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I am allowing user to upload `image/doc` files and for that am using MongoDB `GridFS` . I am able to upload `images, doc files and pdf` of limited size (around `5 MB`) and its stored as desired (single entry), which is then used to fetch data and display on frontend.

The code to upload the file is as follows

```
$conn = new MongoClient();
$db = $conn->selectDB('mydb');
$gridfs = $db->getGridFS('uploads');

$ObjId = new MongoId();
$uniqId = (string)$ObjId;

$uploadedIds = array();

foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    $id = $gridfs->storeFile($file['tmp_name'], array("metadata" => array(
        'filename' => $file['name'],
        'type' => $file['type'],
        "id"=> 2,
        "parentId" => "1",
        "name" => "Employee Reference",
        "title" => "Employee Reference",
        "isFolder" => 1
    )));

    $id = $gridfs->storeFile($file['tmp_name'], array(
        '_id' => $ObjId,
        "id" => $uniqId,
        'filename' => $file['name'],
        'type' => $file['type'],
        "parentId" => "10",
        "title" => $file['name'], 
        isFolder" => 0
    ));
}

$conn->close();
```

But when I try to upload a `PDF` with size around `8 MB`, it stores the data in following format.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54226f4c920662240a000080"),
    "filename" : "blob",
    "type" : "application/octet-stream",
    "title" : "blob",
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-09-24T07:14:20.000Z"),
    "length" : 338277,
    "chunkSize" : 261120,
    "md5" : "d4f9269491c30a0ab086b3bab02c81ee"
}
```

As you can see above, the file gets divided according to `length` and for a single `PDF`, it inserts around `8` entries.

How can I fetch the data for large files in one and show file name and other details on frontend ?

Thanks.

Comment: What library are you using? It'd be helpful to share a snippet of the code responsible for storing the file, regardless of whether you're using a library or the PHP driver alone. "Single entry" is strange, as the default chunk size is 256k. Also, given how [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) works, even the smallest file would consist of two documents: one each in `fs.files`  and `fs.chunks` (note: `fs` may be customized).

Comment: @jmikola, I have added the upload code. `fs.file` and `fs.chunks` are okay, but `fs.files` is having multiple insert entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no reason to call `storeFile()` multiple times on the same file. That is going to create an additional `fs.files` document and redundant `fs.chunks` documents.

In your first call to `storeFile()`, you're nesting all of the metadata under a `metadata` field, which is likely not what you want. The `$metadata` argument to the GridFS storage methods is essentially merged into the `fs.files` document that will be created, which is why the documentation alludes to using the `_id` within `$metadata` if one is provided; otherwise, the driver generates a new MongoId instance. The `$metadata` argument in your second call to `storeFile()` looks more typical.

Since you're including an `isFolder` field in your metadata arrays, I think you might be wrongfully assuming that GridFS supports a directory structure. GridFS is nothing more than a convention, shared by various drivers, for storing binary blobs in a collection. The `fs.files` record hold metadata (core fields are outlined [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#gridfs-files-collection)) and all binary data is stores in one or more related `fs.chunks` documents (linked back to the `fs.files` identifier).

It's possible to simulate a directory structure with GridFS by way of the metadata fields, but it's not a stock feature. For instance, you could add a `path` metadata field, which would always store a canonical directory path (e.g. your app would normalize `/foo/bar/../bar` as `/foo/bar` before storage), and then create an index of `fs.files` requiring the `path` and `filename` combination to be unique. It would be entirely up to your application to keep track of this.

---

Since you're storing an uploaded file (referenced in `$_FILES`), you may want to use [`MongoGridFS::storeUpload()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongogridfs.storeupload.php), which takes the field name (i.e. `$_FILES` key) as its first argument and automatically populates a `filename` field in the `fs.files` document based on the name provided by the user. Generally, the client-side filename is arbitrary (so don't blindly trust it or expect it to be unique/accurate); however, it's worth storing if you plan to show it back to the user in your UI.

As a last thought, there is generally no reason to call [MongoClient::close()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.close.php) at the end of your script. The documentation even advises against it, as it defeats the driver's ability to manage persistent connections.